# ffmpeg scroll text without gap

Tags: video, ffmpeg, overlay

I'm using this command to scroll text on video

```
"drawbox=y=ih-108:color=blue@0.4:\
width=iw:height=48:t=fill, \
drawtext=textfile=file.txt: \ 
fontfile=OpenSans-Regular.ttf: \
y=h-line_h-65:\
x=w-mod(max(t-1.5\,0)*(w+tw)/18.5\, (w+tw)): \
fontcolor=white:fontsize=36" \
```

This scroll runs in loop with gap. When all the text is scrolled on video [there's a gap] then it restarts the scroll.

I want scroll to run continuously without any gap like in this video -
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z0ZpLAgpghk

Is there any other filter to accomplish this 
or how do i modify the `x=` expression to get desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by chaining two drawtext filters

```
"drawbox=y=ih-108:color=blue@0.4:\
width=iw:height=48:t=fill, \
drawtext=textfile=file.txt: \ 
fontfile=OpenSans-Regular.ttf: \
y=h-line_h-65:\
x=w-mod(max(t-START_TIME_OFFSET\,0)*(SPEED)\, 2*(tw+MARGIN)): \
fontcolor=white:fontsize=36, \
drawtext=textfile=file.txt: \ 
fontfile=OpenSans-Regular.ttf: \
y=h-line_h-65:\
x=w-mod(max(t-(tw+MARGIN)/(SPEED)-START_TIME_OFFSET\,0)*(SPEED)\, 2*(tw+MARGIN)): \
fontcolor=white:fontsize=36"
```

`START_TIME_OFFSET` is the initial time when the text appears e.g. `1.5` seconds.
`SPEED` is the scrolling distance for one character per second e.g. `100` pixels or 1/10th the width, `w/10`.
`MARGIN` is the distance between the end of one scroll and the start of the next e.g. `100` pixels or proportional distance `w/5`.

For this method, text has to be equal to or wider than frame width.

Comment: I'm getting error msg -                                                 [h264 @ 0x55bd20ad7200] co located POCs unavailable
[h264 @ 0x55bd20af8500] co located POCs unavailable
[Parsed_drawtext_3 @ 0x55bd20af3480] Failed to configure input pad on Parsed_drawtext_3peed=N/A    
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
[aac @ 0x55bd20a83140] Qavg: 152.432
[aac @ 0x55bd20a83140] 2 frames left in the queue on closing
Conversion failed!

Comment: That's an input file decoding error - unrelated to filtering.

Comment: input file is ok. It's working with previous command i posted

Comment: Add -report and rerun. Share report.

Comment: Link to report file - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PE0YICMiwZYCorYkuD8SyVsQ7BMRHlin/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Added missing 2nd arg in max function in first drawtext

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102504/discussion-between-ramjivan-jangid-and-gyan).